# Migrate from Birt Report for pdf reports

Tags: java, node.js, performance, birt, pdfmake

My company is currently using Birt report to generate different pdf files like invoices, bank reports, etc.

But as the number of users have increased, we are having some troubles because Birt consumes a lot of resources and from time to time that consumption makes the report service crash. We need to investigate the problem but given that it is an old technology we are also thinking about a migration (We are considering node.js with pdfmake).

What would you recommend? Maybe another library for java?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am one of the committers of the BIRT project.

What release of BIRT are you using?
Did you know that the BIRT project is in fact alive again (see https://github.com/eclipse/birt) ?

It's true, BIRT's memory consumption can be quite high sometimes.
I am also a user of BIRT. For our commercial application, we have written a BIRT server consisting of several Java processes.
Althought BIRT supports multi-threading, each of our processes is running at most one BIRT report at a given time.
We are dynamically controlling the number of these processes, so we can adjust them to the load.

So we can, for example, assure that at most 10 reports are running in parallel.

Furthermore, we distinguish between simple and complex reports.
For the complex reports, we grant more heap size to the Java processes, but we limit the number of theses processes to eg. 2.

If you are facing OutOfMemoryErrors, then you should consider using a similar process.

This way our system can easily create thousands of reports/day on a single machine.

I won't recommend using a different software.

Other tools that I know which seem suitable are JasperReports and reportlab (if you just need PDF output). The latter one lets you program reports, it's not a graphical tool - I know that the iText library was inspired by it.

What is your load, anyway?

I think many tools should be able to create 1000s of reports per day. The trick is to avoid running too many reports at the same time, and this is probably independent of the tool used. Also take into account that running too many reports will put high load onto your database system, which will slow down things further, so it's not just the app server's CPU and memory and Java GC. Unfortunately performance problems in the DB and on your app server not only add up, but increase each other further (sorry for my bad english).